# get all routes in a vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to create a simple menu using vue router, I'd like to iterate all routes and display them in my menu, currently I am using below instance method in my component but I just get a function, how would I iterate to get individual routes?

```
methods : {
 getMenuLinks: function() {
        
        var t = this.$router.map() ;
        //t returns a vue object instance
        return t._children ;
        // did not know how to iterate this 
   }

 }
```

I want to iterate all maped routes to get something like below of each mapped route:

```
<a v-link="{ path: 'home' }">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In Nuxt, the routes are generated automatically so I couldn't do what @zxzak suggested.

Here's what you can do in that case.

```html
<template v-for="item in items">
    <b-nav-item :to="item.path">
        {{item.name}}
    </b-nav-item>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
    created() {
        this.$router.options.routes.forEach(route => {
            this.items.push({
                name: route.name
                , path: route.path
            })
        })
    }
    , data() {
        return {
            items: []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , actually there was a bug in vue-1 router that made me post this ...see date, anyway thanks for solution logic ,kudos.

Comment: Where is the official doc of `$router.options.routes`?

Comment: `$router.options.routes` will only have the initial set of routes. Anything added with `addRoutes` will be not present there.

Comment: `$router.options` is private API (also not available in TypeScript):
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2051#issuecomment-363686410

Comment: Some of the routes were not in my case.

Comment: What if we want a full flat list of all routes ? Because `router.options.routes` returns the hierarchy like it is defined in the router (with children and so on). In that case, you could use `$router.getRoutes()`

Answer (score 27):

You can simply iterate over `$router.options.routes` in your template:

```
<nav>
  <router-link v-for="route in $router.options.routes" :key="route.path" :to="route.path">{{ route.name }}</router-link>
</nav>
```

Maybe add styling for the selected route:

```
:class="{ active: route.path === $router.currentRoute.path }"
```

edit: for active class, use https://router.vuejs.org/api/#active-class instead

Comment: Nice! but why do routes that are added with router.addRoutes() do not appear in that list?

Comment: @stallingOne the option object never changes, says the corresponding github issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2280. weird behavior, I agree

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but because I am using NUXT and it renders the routes according to folders, how can I include that hierarchy in the returned links?

Answer (score 10):

Since vue-router 3.5, Router instance has now a getRoutes() method.
So an up to date answer could be

```html
<router-link 
    for="r in routes" 
    :key="r.path" 
    :to="r.path"
>
    {{ r.name }}
</router-link>
```

```js
computed: {
    routes() { return this.$router.getRoutes() }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of relaying on Vue's internals, put routes inside the data of your starting component.

```
var map = {
  '/foo': {
    component: Foo
  },
  '/bar': {
    component: Bar
  }
}

var routes = Object.keys(map)

var App = Vue.extend({
  data: function() {
    return {
      routes: routes
    }
  }
})

router.map(map)
router.start(App, '#app')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xyu276sa/380/

Comment: router.start() is not used in current version https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration-vue-router.html#router-start-replaced

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using Webpack's [`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext)

```
// search for src/pages/**/index.vue
function routesGen () {
  const pages = require.context('./pages/', true, /index\.vue$/)
  const filePaths = pages.keys()
  const getRoutePath = filePath => filePath.match(/\.(\/\S+)\/index\.vue/)[1]
  return filePaths.map(filePath => ({
    path: getRoutePath(filePath),
    component: pages(filePath).default
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `VueRouter` is simply a JavaScript class as other classes, you can extend it and add any custom functionality including the questionable one:

```
// TypeScript

import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter, { RouteConfig } from 'vue-router';

class VueRouterEx extends VueRouter {
  matcher: any;

  public routes: RouteConfig[] = [];

  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    const { addRoutes } = this.matcher;
    const { routes } = options;

    this.routes = routes;

    this.matcher.addRoutes = (newRoutes) => {
      this.routes.push(...newRoutes);
      addRoutes(newRoutes);
    };
  }
}

Vue.use(VueRouterEx);

const router = new VueRouterEx({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [],
});

export default router;
```

So, from any component, you can get the routes using `this.$router.routes`